# C++ thread_pool with heterogeneous work-queue

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++17

I have read the book "C++ concurrency in action" and understood the thread_pool implementation. I have changed a few things according to my project requirements.

I have used `std::variant` to support heterogeneous `work-queue` to store different task arriving on a `epoll-event` loop. Currently In my project I have only two different types of task arrive on the epoll loop. Those are `TaskECB` and `TaskRPCB`. I have created classes for both of them and overloaded the `operator()`

```
#define THREAD_POOL_SIZE 100
std::map<std::string,std::string> tidToTname;

template<typename T>
class threadSafeQueue {
    private:
        mutable std::mutex mut;
        std::queue<std::shared_ptr<T>> taskQueue;   /*  task as pushed here and 
                                                        task are processed in FIFO
                                                        style */
        std::condition_variable dataCond;           /* used to protect the queue */
    public:
        threadSafeQueue(){}
        void waitAndPop(T& value);      /* wait untill task is not available in 
                                           the queue */
        std::shared_ptr<T> waitAndPop();/* same but returns a shared pointer */
        bool tryPop(T& value);          /* does not block */
        std::shared_ptr<T> tryPop();    /* does not block and returns a pointer*/
        void Push(T newData);
        bool Empty() const;             /* check if queue is empty or not */
        void notifyAllThreads();        /* notify all the waiting threads
                                           used in Thpool decallocation */
};

template<typename T>
void threadSafeQueue<T>::notifyAllThreads() {
    dataCond.notify_all();
}
template<typename T>
void threadSafeQueue<T>::waitAndPop(T& value) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mut);
    dataCond.wait(lk,[this](){return !taskQueue.empty();});
    value = std::move(*taskQueue.front());
    taskQueue.pop();
}
template<typename T>
std::shared_ptr<T> threadSafeQueue<T>::waitAndPop() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mut);
    dataCond.wait(lk,[this](){return !taskQueue.empty();});
    std::shared_ptr<T> res = taskQueue.front();
    taskQueue.pop();
    return res;
}

template<typename T>
bool threadSafeQueue<T>::tryPop(T& value) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mut);
    if(taskQueue.empty())
        return false;
    value = std::move(*taskQueue.front());
    taskQueue.pop();
    return true;
}
template<typename T>
std::shared_ptr<T> threadSafeQueue<T>::tryPop() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mut);
    if(taskQueue.empty())
        return std::shared_ptr<T>(); /* return nullptr */
    std::shared_ptr<T> res = taskQueue.front();
    taskQueue.pop();
    return res;
}
template<typename T>
void threadSafeQueue<T>::Push(T newData) { /* TODO: size check before pushing */
    std::shared_ptr<T> data(std::make_shared<T>(std::move(newData)));
                                           /* construct the object before lock*/
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mut);
    taskQueue.push(data);
    dataCond.notify_one();
}
template<typename T>
bool threadSafeQueue<T>::Empty() const {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mut);
    return taskQueue.empty();
}

class TaskRPCB { /* Task RecvAndProcessCallbacks */
    private:
        int len;
        uint fdId;
        int streamId;
        void* msgBlob;
        std::function<void(void*,int,uint,int)> func;
    public:
        TaskRPCB(std::function<void(void*,int,uint,int)>&f , void* msgBlob,int len,
            uint fdId, int streamId) {
            this->func = f;
            this->msgBlob = msgBlob;
            this->len = len;
            this->fdId = fdId;
            this->streamId = streamId;
        }
        void operator()() {
            higLog("%s","TaskRPCB function is executing...");
            func(msgBlob,len,fdId,streamId);
        }
};

class TaskECB { /* Task eventCallBack */
    private:
        std::function<void(void)> func;
    public:
        TaskECB(std::function<void(void)>&f) : func(f) {}
        void operator()() {
            higLog("%s","TaskECB function is executing...");
            func();
        }
};

typedef variant<TaskECB,TaskRPCB> taskTypes;

class Thpool {
    std::atomic_bool done;
    threadSafeQueue<taskTypes> workQ;
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    void workerThread() {
        auto tid = std::this_thread::get_id();
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << tid;
        std::string s = ss.str();
        while(!done) {
            auto task = workQ.waitAndPop();
            if(task != nullptr and !done) {
                printf("%s is executing now : ",tidToTname[s].c_str());
                if((*task).index() == 0) {      // TODO: change 0 and 1 to enums
                    auto func = get<TaskECB>(*task);
                    func();
                }else if((*task).index() == 1) {
                    auto func = get<TaskRPCB>(*task);
                    func();                 
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public:
        Thpool(): done(false) {
        // unsigned const maxThreadCount = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
        unsigned const maxThreadCount = THREAD_POOL_SIZE;
        printf("ThreadPool Size = %d",maxThreadCount);
            /* save thread names for logging purpose */
            std::vector<std::string> tnames;
            for(unsigned int i = 0;i<maxThreadCount;i++) {
                tnames.push_back("Thread_" + std::to_string(i+1));
            }

            try { /* exception might arise due to thread creation */
                for(unsigned int i = 0;i<maxThreadCount;i++) {
                    threads.push_back(std::thread(&Thpool::workerThread,this));
                    /*map this ith threadID to a name Thread_i*/
                    auto tid = threads[i].get_id();
                    std::stringstream ss;
                    ss << tid;
                    tidToTname[ss.str()] = tnames[i];
                }
            }catch(...) {
                done = true;
                throw;
            }
        }
        ~Thpool() {
            // done = true;
        }
        template<typename taskType>
        void submit(taskType task) {
            workQ.Push(task);
        }
        void deAllocatePool() {
            done = true;
            workQ.notifyAllThreads();
            // unsigned const maxThreadCount = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
            unsigned const maxThreadCount = THREAD_POOL_SIZE;
            for(unsigned int i = 0;i<maxThreadCount;) {
                if(threads[i].joinable()) {
                    threads[i].join();
                    i++; /* go for the next thread in the pool */
                }else {
                    workQ.notifyAllThreads();
                }
            }
        }
};
/*============== Thread Pool code ends ============== */
```

How I use this `thread_pool` ?

```
Thpool pool;
```

Following code will be inserted in required functions. I am showing for the `TaskRPCB` type task only.

```
std::function<void(void*,int,uint,int)> func = NFVInstance->CallBackTable[channel];
/* create a task object : members of it :
    - the callback function
    - msgBlob
    - len of the msgBlob
    - some other ID
    - stream ID on which this message was received
*/
TaskRPCB task(func,msg,rc,fdd.id,streamId);
/* submit this task to the pool.
    one of the waiting threads will pick this task
*/
pool.submit(task);
```

Comment: sorry for mixing tags. I would like to have suggestions regarding thread pool implementation overall and the use of` std:: variant` ? is it ok ? or does it have some performance penalty?

Comment: I've edited tags to C++17 (since `std::variant` requires that).  I hope you get good reviews!

Comment: `THREAD_POOL_SIZE 100` I hope you are running on some large hardware. The point os a thread pool is that you create a thread for each available processor (or very close to that) then each processor gets new work from the pool without having to switch threads (as that is a relatively expensive operation).

Answer (score 4):

Naming nits:

- Why `threadSafeQueue` instead of `ThreadSafeQueue`? You CamelCaps all your other class names. Why not this one?
- `class TaskECB { /* Task eventCallBack */` is a very verbose way of writing `class TaskEventCallback {`. If you have to spell it out in a comment anyway, just spell it out *in the code*. Your readers will thank you.
- `bool threadSafeQueue<T>::Empty() const`: Since you're diverging from the traditional STL naming convention anyway (`Empty` is not `empty`), I recommend prefixing boolean accessors with `Is`, as in, `myQueue.IsEmpty()`. This way you don't confuse it with the verb "to empty," as in, "this function *empties* the queue." Orthogonally, you might mark this function `[[nodiscard]]` just to emphasize that it has no side effects.
- `deAllocatePool()` would more traditionally be spelled `deallocatePool()`. "Deallocate" is a single word in English.

---

```
template<typename T>
void threadSafeQueue<T>::Push(T newData) { /* TODO: size check before pushing */
    std::shared_ptr<T> data(std::make_shared<T>(std::move(newData)));
                                           /* construct the object before lock*/
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mut);
    taskQueue.push(data);
    dataCond.notify_one();
}
```

Personally, I would simplify this to

```
template<class T>
void threadSafeQueue<T>::Push(T newData) { /* TODO: size check */
    auto data = std::make_shared<T>(std::move(newData));
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mut);
    taskQueue.push(std::move(data));
    dataCond.notify_one();
}
```

Notice the use of `=` for initialization — it helps distinguish `bool foo(int)` from `bool foo(true)`, and helps readability in general. I also put a `std::move` on the push, so that we're not unnecessarily copying the `shared_ptr` and incurring an extra atomic increment and decrement of the refcount. (No big deal.) Notice that we are *still* incurring an extra call to `T`'s move-constructor; we might want to take `T` by reference here, in which case we might want two versions — one that takes `const T&` and one that takes `T&&`.

In fact, we might want to cut out the middleman entirely:

```
template<class T>
template<class... Args>
void threadSafeQueue<T>::Emplace(Args&&... args) { /* TODO: size check */
    auto data = std::make_shared<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mut);
    taskQueue.push(std::move(data));
    dataCond.notify_one();
}
```

---

```
typedef variant<TaskECB,TaskRPCB> taskTypes;
```

You're missing a `std::` there. Also, isn't it weird to have a *single* type named `taskTypes` (plural)? When I see the name "task**Types**", I expect to see *multiple* types — like a parameter pack or something. Here I think this type alias wants to be just a `taskType` or `taskVariant`, singular.

---

```
    auto tid = std::this_thread::get_id();
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << tid;
    std::string s = ss.str();
```

Yuck. In an ideal world, `std::to_string(std::this_thread::get_id())` would Do The Right Thing; but we don't live in an ideal world.

However, why are you using `std::string` as your map key, anyway? Why not just define

```
std::map<std::thread::id, std::string> tidToTname;
```

and skip the expensive stringification?

Then, instead of

```
printf("%s is executing now : ",tidToTname[s].c_str());
```

you would write simply

```
printf("%s is executing now : ",tidToTname.at(tid).c_str());
```

(notice that we no longer risk *modifying* `tidToTname` accidentally!), and instead of

```
tidToTname[ss.str()] = tnames[i];
```

you'd write simply

```
tidToTname.insert_or_assign(tid, tnames[i]);
```

(Still beware: using `emplace` instead of `insert_or_assign` will still compile, but it will do the wrong thing if the key is already present! The STL's `map` is a very tricky beast. You have to be careful with it.)

---

```
if((*task).index() == 0) {      // TODO: change 0 and 1 to enums
    auto func = get<TaskECB>(*task);
    func();
}else if((*task).index() == 1) {
    auto func = get<TaskRPCB>(*task);
    func();                 
}
```

First of all, `(*task).index()` is traditionally spelled `task->index()`, and I strongly recommend that you do so. Nested parentheses make things hard to read. That's why the `->` operator was added to C back in the '70s! (Probably late '60s, actually. Maybe earlier.)

Second, this is not a typical way to interact with `std::variant`. The library really intends you to interact with it like this:

```
std::visit([](auto& callback) {
    callback();
}, *task);
```

If you want to preserve your inefficient copying, just change `auto&` to `auto`.

Really, IMO, it should be `const auto&`; but in order to make that work, you'll have to make your `callback` types const-callable. Right now their `operator()`s are non-const member functions:

```
void operator()() /* NO CONST HERE -- INTENTIONAL? */ {
    higLog("%s","TaskECB function is executing...");
    func();
}
```

If you're allergic to `visit` — which you shouldn't be! — but if you are, then a *slightly* more idiomatic way to write your chain of `if`s would be

```
if (auto *func = std::get_if<TaskECB>(task.get())) {
    (*func)();
} else if (auto *func = std::get_if<TaskRPCB>(task.get())) {
    (*func)();
}
```

Having to use `task.get()` to get a raw pointer, instead of just `task` or `*task`, definitely isn't ideal API design on the STL's part. But again, the ideal solution is to just use `std::visit`! You should use `std::visit`.

---

I didn't check the multithreading parts. Odds are, there are bugs. Multithreaded code always has at least one bug. :)

Comment: You mentioned `->` was created in the 70s, maybe the 60s.  At least in C, it wouldn't have been added before `struct`, and thanks to some UNIX preservation work, we can put that in the 1972 - 1973 timeframe.

https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/primevalC.html

The last1120c version has no `struct` support.  prestruct-c does (including `->`); it's the last version before the compiler began to make use of `struct` itself.

Answer (score 2):

Some additions to the review from @Quuxpluson.

With regard to threadsafety, i'd be concerned that you are not calling `deAllocatePool` in the destructor. It's undefined behavior to call a destructor on `std::mutex` when the mutex is locked. It is also *a bad thing* to call the destructor on `std::thread` when it is considered `joinable`. Both of these may happen if you destruct your threadpool without clearing out the work queue.

Looking further at your `deAllocatePool`, I think that you could get into cases where you can't end a thread. You are setting `done` but if the queue is empty, the thread could be waiting in `waitAndPop()`. While the `notifyAllThreads` will cause it to wake the lambda expression that you are using in your `wait` statement

```
dataCond.wait(lk,[this](){return !taskQueue.empty();});
```

would immediately go back into a wait state after awoken. If you manage to call `join()` on this kind of thread your `deallocatePool` would hang. I think is that checking for an abort condition inside the wait would mitigate that. If this hasn't happened yet there could be a variety of issues, i could be wrong, your use pattern has prevented this, or just pure coincidence ...

Both of your task types could be reduced to a functor with the type `std::function<void(void)>`. You could use either lambdas or `std::bind` to enclose the state information, this would reduce the complexity inside your threadpool.